# What does this line of code reference: "var io = require('../..')(server);"?

Tags: sockets, io, websocket, server

I followed this tutorial to create a chatroom using socket.io: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io.

I then created a page incorporating the chatroom (within the tutorial file structure) and now I am trying to export this into a different project...

I can't seem to do this without incorporating ALL the files from this tutorial.

I think I have narrowed down the issue to be this one line of code within the chat index.js page:

`var io = require('../..')(server);`

What does the above line reference to within the tutorial? 
The error I get in my new project structure is this:

```
module.js:339
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module '../..'
```

Here is a link to the index.js file that has that line of code:
    https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/examples/chat/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require()` accepts a module name or a path to a module.

Per the node.js docs for `require()`, one of the argument options leads to this:

```
LOAD_AS_DIRECTORY(X)
1. If X/package.json is a file,
   a. Parse X/package.json, and look for "main" field.
   b. let M = X + (json main field)
   c. LOAD_AS_FILE(M)
2. If X/index.js is a file, load X/index.js as JavaScript text.  STOP
3. If X/index.json is a file, parse X/index.json to a JavaScript object. STOP
4. If X/index.node is a file, load X/index.node as binary addon.  STOP
```

This would mean that `../..` is trying to go up the directory tree and load `package.json`, `index.js`, `index.json` or `index.node` from that directory.

You can read about the allowed syntax for `require()` [here in the node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_accessing_the_main_module).

FYI, there's a chat room demo on the socket.io site [here](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/).

Comment: here is the url of the index within the tutorial: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/examples/chat/index.js

Comment: I tried replacing it with what you have and installing the socket.io module (since the tutorial doesn't use socket.io module- instead it has: socket.io-adapter, socket.io-client, and socket.io-parser) and it didn't work :(

Comment: Well I've already done those other tutorials and have been successful. I also was successful with the tutorial I posted. My only issue is trying to export just the chat files to another project I am working on... however that one line of code seems to be the reason why I can't do this... I don't know what that line of code does....

Comment: @xgrioux - see how I've modified my answer.  If you pass a directory path to `require()` which `../..` is, it looks for some well known filenames in that directory to load those.  So, you must be missing a desired file by one of those names in the parent directory.

Comment: Thankyou! That explains a lot!